# Turn off Sticky Keys at login screen

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-layout

I know how to disable Sticky Keys on the Desktop, but it still pop-ups on the login screen.  Is there anyway to disable it so it never shows on the login screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

1. Open an [elevated command prompt](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/command-prompt-faq#1TC=windows-7).
2. Type or paste the following command, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

   ```
   reg add "HKU\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Accessibility\StickyKeys" /v "Flags" /t REG_SZ /d "506" /f
   ```

### References

- [Disable FilterKeys, StickyKeys, and ToggleKeys](http://unattended.msfn.org/unattended.xp/view/registry/17/)
- [Disabling StickyKeys for Good.](http://blog.duklabs.com/?p=96)